# How is exception handling implemented in Java?

Tags: java, assembly, exception, compilation

How is exception handling implemented in higher-level programming languages (like Java)? By this, I don't mean how to use exceptions within a language; I mean how the compiler generates code (assembly, or some intermediate, like Java byte code) that we recognize as exception-handling, because in the end, the computer can execute only instructions; Everything of a higher-level must be comprised of those instructions.

In C, before exceptions existed, you would return an error code, but if a function already returns something, then what? Perhaps return a structure of both the error code and the real result?

Comment: You can think of it as having two, alternative return values. Either it will return a value (like an string or number or nothing) or it will return an error condition. Both are just a little bundle of data. The calling code that is generated must detect which happened and handle it. Perhaps it gets caught there. Perhaps that calling method/function will return the error condition.

Comment: In C you can also use a pair of special functions (`setjmp()` and `longjmp()`) in order to return to a previous point bypassing one or more of normal function returns. These functions record and restore the minimum CPU state (typically, just a few registers) in/from a structure to facilitate such "jumps".

Comment: 4 'not constructive votes'? Please. The question does have a single factual answer, to be found in the JVM Specification.

Comment: @LeeMeador So, what a try-block does is make all function calls inside of it check the error condition part of the returned structure for the errors that the catch declares, and then either jumps to the appropriate error-handling block, or if the error isn't caught, then the call-stack just keeps unwinding until either a lower frame catches it, or there's no frames left and the program just terminates. Is this right?

Comment: Yep. Except you can think of the JVM as putting a catch `Throwable` at the very top of the call stack. If your `main` "returns" with an exception, it gets caught at the very top. I think it prints a message if you are running command line. JEE containers do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler outputs an `athrow` instruction ([JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.athrow)) at the throw site, and an `Exceptions` attribute ([#4.7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.5)) in the code of the method that shows where all the various catch clauses are, what range of instructions they cover, and what exception types they catch.

Comment: So, after the JVM executes the `athrow` instruction, it checks the type of the object reference thrown, compares it to the exceptions listed in the exception attribute, and then jumps to the appropriate one. Is this right? What if the exception is not in the list?

Comment: If the exception isn't caught by anything in the list it propagates outward from the method to the caller, ...